# How to make it clear when laptop is on battery in 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, icons, battery, customization

In Ubuntu 18.04, the default icons showing whether the laptop is on battery or plugged in, are quite similar:

- [image: screenshot] → Plugged in
- [image: screenshot]  → Battery

Its really easy to miss when the laptop accidentally unplugs.

Is there a way to make the  icons different, or to make it more prominent when the laptop is on battery?

Answer (score 11):

From the attached pics in your Question gives clue that those icons are named as

`battery-good-charging-symbolic.svg` and
`battery-good-symbolic.svg`

[image]

There are similar Images with naming which can be understood easily.

First determine which icon theme is being used.

And then copying this Icon theme into `~/.icons` directory and replacing the image with your preferred one but with same name of icon will change the symbol.

There is a good documentation [here](https://developer.gnome.org/icon-theme-spec/).

Comment: `ls: cannot access '/home/ali/.icons': No such file or directory` ? I'm using the dark theme

Comment: @ClickUpvote you’ll need to create that directory.

Answer (score 9):

I solved this by going to *Tweaks → Top Bar* → Turn on *Battery Percentage*.

[image: screenshot]

Now the battery percentage is shown as a number, so if unplugged, the number shows as declining which is more attention grabbing than the icons.

[image: screenshot]